# DialogFlow: referring to people by name

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

How can I provide knowledge to DialogFlow so that it understands a query like:

```
Intent #1   : My name is Tim and I'm 36
Response #1 : I understand your name is Tim and you're 36
Intent #2   : My partner's name is Jane and she's 35
Response #2 : I understand your partner's name is Jane and she's 35
Intent #3   : How old am I?
Response #3 : You are 36

Intent #4   : How old is Jane?
Response #4 : Jane is 35
```

Assume Intent #1/2 are processed by webhooks, and Response #1/2 are validations that the webhook understands and can store data like `Tim`, `Jane`, `36` and `35`.

To demonstrate, Intent #3 is processed by a webhook that can retrieve `36`.

Intent #4 could presumably match things like `How old is my partner` and `What's my partner's age`. But how can DialogFlow understand that `Jane` should be replaced by `partner` when parsing the input?

I sort of need a way to match `How old is $partnerName`.

Answer (score 0):

On a high level:

- You will create 4 parameters yourName, partnerName, yourAge, partnerAge.
- Capture these parameters in an intent using @sys.givenName for names entities and @sys.number for age.
- Save the values in DB or cache it from webhook.
- Use them for later use in bot's responses.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how can I use the values as part of Intent #4? How can I match `Jane`?

Comment: you may need to keep some mapping in DB like primary user and partner. So if Tim is the primary user then Jane will be the partner or vice versa. Also, you may require some kind of Authentication to identify the primary user or you may ask upfront are you(Tim) the primary user and process the responses based on the answer.

Comment: I understand. But I think you're still missing the critical question: how to tell DialogFlow to parse `Jane` during the Intent phase. I sort of need the Intent to say `How old is $partnerName`

Comment: I have updated the main question to clarify. Apologies for confusion